# Output arbitrary number as unicode

Tags: c++, unicode, cout

How can I make an arbitrary number be interpreted as Unicode when outputted to the terminal?

So for example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int euro_dec = 0x20AC;

    std::cout << "from int: " << euro_dec
              << "\nfrom \\u: \u20AC" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
from int: 8364
from \u: €
```

What does the escape sequence `\u` do to make the number `0x20AC` be interpreted as Unicode?

I tested using `wcout` and the output was:

```
from int: 8364
from \u:
```

Comment: wchar_t euro_dec = 0x20ac;

Comment: Nothing you do in your code has the slightest bearing on whether the result is interpreted as Unicode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A unicode escape sequence occurring in program text is converted to the equivalent Unicode character at the very first phase of translation (2.2p1b1 **[lex.phases]**). This occurs even before the program is tokenized or preprocessed.

To convert a Unicode codepoint expressed as an integer to your native narrow multibyte encoding, use [`c32rtomb`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/c32rtomb):

```
#include <cuchar>

char buf[MB_CUR_MAX];
std::mbstate_t ps{};
std::size_t ret = std::c32rtomb(buf, euro_dec, &ps);
if (ret != static_cast<std::size_t>(-1)) {
    std::cout << std::string(buf, &buf[ret]);   // outputs €
}
```

Note that `cuchar` is poorly supported; if you know that your native narrow string encoding is UTF-8 you can use [`codecvt_utf8<char32_t>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8) but otherwise you'll have to use platform-specific facilities.

Comment: What header is `std::c32rtomb` in? I'm using gcc 4.9 and I only seem to have the C version, `uchar.h`?

Comment: @Lerp gcc appears to be broken - https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60263

Answer (score 0):

When you output the integer variable, the library converts the value to text, it doesn't actually output the value as an integer.

When using the `"\u"`, it's the compiler which reads the number and converts it to the appropriate byte sequence which it inserts directly into the literal string.

Comment: I wonder why doesn't `*(char*)(&euro_dec)` work then. Or maybe I do.

Comment: But the binary representation of the Unicode euro _is_ the same as 20AC from my understanding? It's not the same as the various encodings though.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Because the dereferencing give you a single `char`.

Comment: @Lerp Oh wait it's `\u20ac` in one example, and what I've tried to do was treating `20ac` as unicode byte sequence.